# What is the definition/usage of the word "cult" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

In the sentence (from the [New York Times](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/06/travel/cruise-ship-living.html)):

> For a devoted group of “cult cruisers,” the aim is to almost never touch dry land."

is 'cult' an adjective, or is it referencing something else?

Comment: What is the source of this? You should credit them. Plus I think the question needs the context

Comment: In this case, "cult" is used as an adjective to explain that someone is obsessed with some thing or idea, not that they are part of an actual cult.

Answer (score 3):

> For a devoted group of “cult cruisers", the aim is to almost never touch dry land.

I found [this article](https://newstral.com/en/article/en/1218072069/for-a-devoted-group-of-cult-cruisers-the-aim-is-to-almost-never-touch-dry-land-).

*cult* is an attributive noun and acts as an adjective describing *cruisers*.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct)
explains.

> In grammar, a noun adjunct, attributive noun, qualifying noun, noun (pre)modifier, or apposite noun is an optional noun that modifies another noun; functioning similarly to an adjective

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cult) defines cult.

> 2a: great devotion to a person, idea, object, movement, or work

> c: a usually small group of people characterized by such devotion

We could hence say the cult cruisers are a small group of people with great devotion to cruises.